# Same page is getting loaded when trying to load data from other page on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to load data on scrolling to the bottom of page from **dynamicContent.jsp** on the basic of *count* variable that I send from the **index.jsp**. Now the issue is that the below script is getting executed successfully but the *newitems* variable doesn't contain new data from the dynamicContent.jsp; rather it is appending the same index.jsp page content again again on scrolling.

**Page structure is somewhat like this:**

```
<div id="divContent">
        <div class="container">
             ...........
        </div>
        <div id="courses">
             ...........
        </div>
        ......... 3-4 more div .......

</div>
```

**The script that I am using is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=1, isPreviousEventComplete = true, isDataAvailable = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
  if (isPreviousEventComplete && isDataAvailable) {

   /* $(".LoaderImage").css("display", "block"); */

  //fetch new items
    if (isPreviousEventComplete && isDataAvailable) {
        isPreviousEventComplete = false;

        /* $('#status').text('Loading more items...'); */
        $.get('dynamicContent.jsp?count='+count, '', function(newitems){
            count = count + 1;
            $('#divContent').append(newitems);
            isPreviousEventComplete = true;

            if (newitems == '   ') //When data is not available
                isDataAvailable = false;

            /* updatestatus(); */
        });
    }   

  }
 }
});
</script>
```

I tried to debug it on browser and got to know that the *newitems* is containing the same page data. i.e. **index.jsp** and not the `<div>` that should be loaded from **dynamicContent.jsp** on the basis of count.

Please help and suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the cache or the dynamicContent.jsp code

Comment: Is url to `dynamicContent.jsp` correct?

Comment: @madalinivascu I didn't get you ? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: one of those are the problem

Comment: @whipdancer Yes the URL seems to be correct to me. I just noticed single inverted comma ** '' ** after the URL call. Is it something that is causing an issue. I can not cross check the code by running it right now as the code is on my personal system that is currently not with me.

Comment: expect me to read the comment

Comment: @madalinivascu
Not able to edit the code here. Please check:
JSFiddle Link
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/rohit_0903/qndgc5ru/)

Comment: Look at the url as called in your browser dev tool, verify it is correct, verify that it returns the data you are expecting.

Comment: @whipdancer Thanks. The issue has been resolved now.